# Firebase cloud scheduler doesn't run promises

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cron, google-cloud-functions

i have a firebase pubsub scheduled task and i am scheduling it this way:

```
export const notificationTrigger = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("0 20 * * *")
    .onRun(() => {
      console.log("CRON JOB TRIGGERED");
      notificationTriggerHandler();
    });
```

and my `notificationTriggerHandler` looks like this:

```
    export async function notificationTriggerHandler(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            console.log("LOG 1: notificationTrigger handler execution start");
            const response = await firestore().collection("collection_name").get();
            console.log(":LOG 2: GOT RESPONSE");
            for (const doc of response.docs) {
              const docData = doc.data();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR FETCHING : ", e);
          }
        return null
    }
```

now the issue I am facing is whenever this function is triggered it doesn't get past the first `LOG: 1` the execution always stops there and the firestore query is never executed and the `LOG: 2` is never displayed on the console, any reason that might cause this?

and just to be sure i created another document change trigger with calls the same `notificationTriggerHandler` like this:

```
export const notificationTestTrigger = functions.firestore
    .document("test_trigger/{id}")
    .onWrite(notificationTriggerHandler);
```

and when i trigger this from a document change the function run properly and shows me both of the logs, so i am really struggling here to understand why it works with a document change trigger and why it does with a cron job scheduler?

Comment: Does it work if you return the Promise in the PubSub Cloud Function? `.onRun(() => { console.log("CRON JOB TRIGGERED"); return notificationTriggerHandler(); });`. See this [doc page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for explanations.

Comment: yes add return statement